# How to create filter by object name in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, filtering

I have data like this

```
{
  "data": {
    "x": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "y": "yData1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "y": "yData2"
      }
    ],
    "xx": {
      "xxx": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "yyy": "yyyData1"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "yyy": "yyyData2"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

sometime i just want object x or xx or xxx or many sub children in datas, i ready using eval for filter by using object name to return data

```
filter(data: any, key: any) {
    return eval("data." + key)
}
```

any idea ?? because eval in typescript/javascript not recommended

Answer (score 0):

Just use bracket notation in order to use variable values as key:

```
filter(data: any, key: any) {
    return data[key];
}
```

Comment: that function not work if u reach xxx the key must xx.xxx, if using eval it work return value